# lxml ignoring any tags the come between a spcific tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to extract some specific fields from a huge xml file. here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
    <dblp>

<article mdate="2009-09-24" key="journals/jasis/GianoliM09">
<author>Ernesto Gianoli</author>
<author>Marco A. Molina-Montenegro</author>
<title>Insights into the relationship between the <i>h</i>-index and self-citations.</title>
<pages>1283-1285</pages>
<year>2009</year>
<volume>60</volume>
<journal>JASIST</journal>
<number>6</number>
<ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/asi.21042</ee>
<url>db/journals/jasis/jasis60.html#GianoliM09</url>
</article>


<article mdate="2014-09-18" key="journals/iacr/ShiCSL11" publtype="informal publication">
<author>Elaine Shi</author>
<author>T.-H. Hubert Chan</author>
<author>Emil Stefanov</author>
<author>Mingfei Li</author>
<title>blivious RAM with O((log N)<sup>3</sup>) Worst-Case Cost.</title>
<pages>407</pages>
<year>2011</year>
<volume>2011</volume>
<journal>IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive</journal>
<ee>http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/407</ee>
<url>db/journals/iacr/iacr2011.html#ShiCSL11</url>
</article>

<phdthesis mdate="2016-05-04" key="phd/it/Popescu2008">
<author>Razvan Andrei Popescu</author>
<title>Aggregation and adaptation of web services: a semi-automated methodology for the aggregation and adaption of web services.</title>
<year>2008</year>
<school>University of Pisa</school>
<pages>1-206</pages>
<isbn>978-3-8364-6280-8</isbn>
<ee>http://d-nb.info/991165179</ee>
</phdthesis><phdthesis mdate="2007-04-26" key="phd/Tsangaris92">
<author>Manolis M. Tsangaris</author>
<title>Principles of Static Clustering for Object Oriented Databases</title>
<year>1992</year>
<school>Univ. of Wisconsin-Madison</school>
</phdthesis>

<phdthesis mdate="2005-11-30" key="phd/Heuer2002">
<author>Andreas Heuer 0002</author>
<title>Web-Pr&auml;senz-Management im Unternehmen</title>
<year>2002</year>
<school>Univ. Trier, FB 4, Informatik</school>
<ee>http://ubt.opus.hbz-nrw.de/volltexte/2004/144/</ee>
</phdthesis>

<mastersthesis mdate="2002-01-03" key="phd/Schulte92">
<author>Christian Schulte</author>
<title>Entwurf und Implementierung eines &uuml;bersetzenden Systems f&uuml;r das intuitionistische logische Programmieren auf der Warren Abstract Machine.</title>
<year>1991</year>
<school>Universit&auml;t Karlsruhe, Institut f&uuml;r Logik, Komplexit&auml;t und Deduktionssysteme</school>
</mastersthesis>

<phdthesis mdate="2002-01-03" key="phd/Hellerstein95">
<author>Joseph M. Hellerstein</author>
<title>Optimization and Execution Techniques for Queries With Expensive Methods</title>
<year>1995</year>
<school>Univ. of Wisconsin-Madison</school>
</phdthesis>

</dblp>
```

and I use the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/parsing-huge-xml-file-with-lxml-etree-iterparse-in-python) to parse and extract the fields that I'm interested in. The problem arises when I want to extract the title in the first case and the second case because of the  `<i>h</i>` and  `<sup>3</sup>` tags. It seems my code see them as new events but not as a part of `<title>` tag and I get following result:

```
title Insights into the relationship between the
blivious RAM with O((log N)
```

basically I get the title text until the parser meet a new tag.

The problem is I don't know how many of such cases (e.g., different tags) do I have, otherwise I could try to remove them manually. Is there anyway to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware of the lxml data model for element content (in particular the [`tail`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail) property).

The content of the `text` property of this element,

```
<title>Insights into the relationship between the <i>h</i>-index and self-citations.</title>
```

is `Insights into the relationship between the`.

The `h` bit is the `text` of the `<i>` child element and `-index and self-citations.` is the `tail` of the same child.

---

In order to get all the text content of the title, you can use [`itertext()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext). Example:

```
from lxml import etree
 
tree = etree.parse("dblp.xml")  # The XML in the question
titles = tree.xpath("//title")
 
for title in titles:
    print ''.join(title.itertext())
```

Output:

```
Insights into the relationship between the h-index and self-citations.
blivious RAM with O((log N)3) Worst-Case Cost.
Aggregation and adaptation of web services: a semi-automated methodology for the aggregation and adaption of web services.
Principles of Static Clustering for Object Oriented Databases
Web-Präsenz-Management im Unternehmen
Entwurf und Implementierung eines übersetzenden Systems für das intuitionistische logische Programmieren auf der Warren Abstract Machine.
Optimization and Execution Techniques for Queries With Expensive Methods
```