# lxml Element's text not shown

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I am having trouble with extracting text from an xml file, but it my code won't let me obtain what I am expected to get.

Here is a portion of code.

```
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
titles = root.findall('title')
title = titles[0]
print(title.tag)
print(title.text)  # <-- this line is supposed to get title's text
```

Here is a sample XML file I tested on.

```
<root>
    <title>
        <indexmarker marker="AAA"/>
        <indexmarker marker="BBB"/>
        <indexmarker marker="CCC"/>Text Here
    </title>
</root>
```

Can anyone help me how I can modify the code so that title.text will extract the text without changing the structure of the xml file itself?

I tried the following tests blow but none of them seemed to be helpful

- print(title)
- print(title.attrib)
- print(title.items())
- print(title.values())

Comment: Text in XML can appear in multiple nodes, _especially_ in situations like you have, where you probably have ***six*** text nodes, for all the whitespace blocks between the contained `indexmarker` tags.  You need to find the API method to iterate over a tag's multiple text nodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38462884/407651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As additionally to Andrej’s good solution for understanding the systematic. You can read more details about lxml [properties](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html).

````
from lxml import etree

xml_content = """
<root>
    <title>title regular text 0</title>
    <title>title tail text 1
        <indexmarker marker="AAA"/>
        <indexmarker marker="BBB"/>
        <indexmarker marker="CCC"/>indexmarker tail text
    </title>
    <title>title regular text 2</title>
</root>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_content)

# find a list and take the third element ->what you search
indexmarker_text = root.findall(".//indexmarker")[2].tail
print(indexmarker_text)

# For explanation only, a node object have a tag name and can have a text, attributes and sometimes tail text
for node in root.iter():
    print(node.tag, node.attrib , node.text, node.tail)

# find a list of title objects
title_list = root.findall(".//title")
for elem in title_list:
    print(repr(elem.text))```
````

Answer (score 0):

To get the `"Text Here"` string you can use `tag.itertext()`:

```py
from lxml import etree

xml_content = """
<root>
    <title>
        <indexmarker marker="AAA"/>
        <indexmarker marker="BBB"/>
        <indexmarker marker="CCC"/>Text Here
    </title>
</root>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_content)

last_text = list(root.find("./title").itertext())[-1].strip()
print(last_text)
```

Prints:

```
Text Here
```